# Nintex Workflow was unable to interpret your response- Lazy approval

Tags: nintex-workflow

In our situation for lazy approval, the user responded with "Yes I approve" instead of the one word "yes, ok, approve, approved"

And user got return mail from system as follow

<<< Start>>>

-----Original Message-----

From: exampleWbesite@exampleDomain.com

Sent: exampleUser1 12:55 PM

To: exampleUser2

Subject: RE: ACTION: something Approval Required for something else

Nintex Workflow was unable to interpret your response. Please try again with a clear indication of your approval outcome.

Valid 'approved' responses are:

- approve
- approved
- ok
- yes

Valid 'declined' responses are:

- decline
- declined
- no
- reject
- rejected

---

Yes I approve.

My question is "Is it the default behavior of Lazy approval or something else went wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy Approval requires the response to be on a single line by itself.

In this case, if the phrase "Yes I approve" was one of the valid approval responses, the result would have been an approval.